# How to redirect a request to https on ELB, provided that if url is api request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, apache, apache2, amazon-elb

I am using Amazon ELB, what settings do I need to configure in Apache to redirect a request to https, if requested url contains '/api'.
I had Googled and tried to make it manageable by rewrite conditions and rules, but it was not able to complete the process and results in a redirect loop.

Answer (score 1):

In the elb you need to configure both https and http to forward traffic to port 80 on your webserver machine.

Then in apache you need to configure a reerite rule. Here is a post that describe that well.

[redirect to http](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23706215/rerouting-all-http-traffic-to-https-with-aws-elb)